# Scala errors "value toInt is not a member of String" and "not found: type"

Tags: scala

I've set up Scala project using Maven. It does not compile however. I get strange errors like something very basic is missing. Some of them are:

```
[ERROR] /home/victor/Work/Projects/Own/Scraper/src/main/scala/me/crawler/Node.scala:17: error: not found: type Map
[INFO]   var attributes: Map[String, String] = null
[INFO]                   ^
[ERROR] /home/victor/Work/Projects/Own/Scraper/src/main/scala/me/crawler/CompanySiteEmailCrawlerController.scala:137: error: not found: type Set
[INFO]   private def addEmailToCompanyList(harvestedRecordsCompanyList: List[Company], company: Company, emailSet: Set[String],[INFO]                                                                                                             ^
[ERROR] /home/victor/Work/Projects/Own/Scraper/src/main/scala/me/crawler/CompanySiteEmailCrawlerController.scala:186: error: value toInt is not a member of String
[INFO]       lineFrom = args(3).toInt
[INFO]                          ^
[ERROR] /home/victor/Work/Projects/Own/Scraper/src/main/scala/me/crawler/crawler4j/Crawler4jAdaptee.scala:25: error: not found: value classOf
[INFO]   private val log: Logger = Logger.getLogger(classOf[Crawler4jAdaptee])
[INFO]                                              ^
[ERROR] /home/victor/Work/Projects/Own/Scraper/src/main/scala/me/crawler/crawler4j/Crawler4jAdaptee.scala:126: error: not found: type Map
[INFO]       val attributesMap: Map[String, String] = attributes.map(a => (a.getKey, a.getValue)).toMap
[INFO]                          ^
```

So `Map` and `Set` collections are not fount and `toInt` method doesn't work for Strings. In my `pom.xml` I have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scala</id>
        <name>Scala Tools</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala</id>
        <name>Scala Tools</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

The same errors I get when I run it in Idea, although the IDE does not complain about the code, only the compiler does. I am quite new to Scala. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: Something similar is with for cycles. I can't use `for (i <- 1 to 10)` instead I have to use `for (i <- Range(0, 10))`, otherwise I get the error `to is not a member of Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Importing `scala.collection.immutable` solved the problems with collections, for the `classOf` problem I found a workaround - using `getClass` instead. `toInt` problem remains unsolved. There is a workaround though - using the exact code from that definition: `java.lang.Integer.parseInt`. I have a feeling that this is also a problem with imports.